# Sharedpreferences crashes the app when trying to retrieve

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I'm very new to Android and was used to iOS. Having a bit of difficult with sharedprefernces. I basically initialize in my settings view for the first time, the high score as 0.

Now in the other game view, when I try to retrieve this score and compare it with the current score to update it, it crashes. As soon as it tries to read it, the app crashes.

This is to initialize in the settings page:

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // similar to view did appear
    System.out.println("Settings viewdidappear");
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    int firstTime = 10;
    SharedPreferences preferences = this.getSharedPreferences("Settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    int getVar = preferences.getInt("CheckVar", 0);

    // set the value first time if not existing already
    if (getVar != 10) {

        System.out.println("Settings not existant: " + getVar);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        getVar = 10;
        editor.putInt("CheckVar", getVar);
        editor.putInt("HighScore", 0);
        editor.commit();

        // add loading for save score


    } else {
        System.out.println("Settings Already Exists: " + getVar);
    }

}
```

And this is in the game page:

```
public class GameLogic extends View {

    SharedPreferences settings;

    public void save(Context context) {
        System.out.println("Running save");

        settings = context.getSharedPreferences("Settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int getVar = settings.getInt("HighScore", 0);
        if (getVar > total_score) {
            System.out.println("Putting new value " + total_score);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            getVar = total_score;
            editor.putInt("HighScore", getVar);
            editor.commit();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Previous score is higher " + getVar);
        }

    }


    public void DidILose() {
        score();

        if (TappedMine == 2) {

            save(null);

            flag_for_loss = 1;
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    getContext());
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Game Over");
            alertDialogBuilder
                    .setMessage("Play again!  \nScore: " + total_score + "\nTime: " + 
                            time_done + " seconds" + "\n Unflagged Mines:" + unflagged_mines)
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                    int id) {
                                    ResetTheGame();
                                }
                            }
                    );
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `if(getVar!=10)` is not true then no key present in `SharedPreferences` with `HighScore` name so use `settings.contains("HighScore")` before retrieving value

Answer (score 0):

you call `save(null);`

and try to use the parameter to access the object, that is `null`, causing a `NullPointerException`, making your application crash

```
 public  void save(Context context) {
        System.out.println("Running save");
        settings = context.getSharedPreferences("Settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: I couldn't figure out what should I pass as a parameter. Can you please suggest

Comment: `View`, has the `getContext()` method. Use it

Comment: I tried doing it without the save method, but it wouldn't let me do that. I read somewhere that I need to use Context object